# mouse hover on the span doesn't work

Tags: css, mousehover

Suppose to have this html:

```
<a href="" class="hoverelement"><span>DOG</span></a>
```

I need to increase size of string "DOG"
So I use this css:

```
.hoverelement span:hover {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

But this does not work? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is wrong with this code? Check [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a7bh8y0u/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `!important` in span's `css`, because it may be inherited by it's parent's rule.

```css
.hoverelement span:hover {
  font-size:20px !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="hoverelement"><span>DOG</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the a-element the `hover`-selector.

```
a.hoverelement:hover span {
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
.hoverelement:hover span {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```